# Xamarin Forms - Allow Two Pages to share the same Code-Behind

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, partial-classes

Here is my usual structure for a Xamarin Forms Page:

**LoginPage.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// UI Code
/// </summary>
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Created the view content
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        // Controls
    }
}
```

**LoginPageCode.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Code Behind
/// </summary>
public partial class LoginPage
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Events
}
```

This works fine for most cases, but for the first time I developing for both mobile phones and tablets.

In this scenario, the UI of the login page for a phone vs. a tablet would be so different that I would want to push a completely different page based on the Device Idiom.

Example:

```
if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPhonePage());
}
else
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginTabletPage());
}
```

Now, it’s only the UI code that is really changing so I would like to keep the same code behind for both pages.

What is the best way to share the same code-behind for both pages so I don’t have to create one for each UI Page?

Comment: I know this is not exactly what you are asking but implementing MVVM in your apps and moving your business code to the ViewModel will allow you to have different Pages with the same logic with little work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need something like this:
http://arteksoftware.com/ioc-containers-with-xamarin/

I think an IoC - Framework is very usefull in your situation...